# Saving related entities with unique index

Tags: c#, sql, entity-framework-5, foreign-key-relationship

I have an `SQL` table named `Person` and it's connected to table `Pets` with many-to-many relationship, `PersonPets`.

I'm trying to save the entity `Person` with `Pets`. But I forced the Pets to be unique by name.

It throws an exception about a foreignkey contraint in the `Pets` table. Which is good, I created that index.

```
public class Person
{
  public string Name { get; set; }
  public string LastName { get; set; }
}

public class Pets
{
  public string Name { get; set; }
}
```

So how can I save the `Person` with the related `Pets` and if they already exists not adding them again, but simply add a reference in the `PersonPets` table?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You must check if a pet with the given name already exists in the database. EF won't do that automatically. You can perform this check with a single query for all pets and replace the found pets in your `person.Pets` collection with the loaded existing pet:

```
Person person... // your new person with a collection of pets

using (var ctx = new MyContext())
{
    var pets = person.Pets;
    var petNames = pets.Select(p => p.Name);
    person.Pets.Clear();

    var existingPetsDict = ctx.Pets
        .Where(p => petNames.Contains(p.Name))
        .ToDictionary(p => p.Name);

    foreach (var pet in pets)
    {
        Pets existingPet;
        if (existingPetsDict.TryGetValue(pet.Name, out existingPet))
            person.Pets.Add(existingPet);
        else
            person.Pets.Add(pet);
    }

    ctx.Persons.Add(person);
    ctx.SaveChanges();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can write a query to check if the Pet name exists.

```
Person person;
< code to init. person with your values >

string myPet = <the input pet name>
var pet = (from p in Pets where p.Name == myPet).FirstOrDefault();

if (pet == null) {
    < code to insert new Pet >
    Pet pet = new Pet();
    pet.Name = myPet;
}

person.Pets.Add(pet);


< code to attach Person / save changes >
```

Comment: Well if it exisits, how to make the relation between the Person and Pet? Doesn't `EntityFramework` do this for me?

Comment: If the navigation properties are set correctly, you can do it that way. You still need to select the existing Pet like the code I wrote above, and then set Person.Pets.Add(pet); Or, you can insert directly to the relation table.

Comment: I made some edits above, hope that will help. Slauma's answer shows a way to check more at once.